# Unreal engine 4.26 Android Error: Unknown Cook Failure on packing

Tags: android, error-handling, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4

I want to start producing Android apps using the Unreal engine, but I ran into a couple of difficulties during the tests.

The first thing I wanted to try is whether I can package this apk at all. I did all the things prescribed by the description,
(I installed that android studio, downloaded and installed the necessary elements, added java, etc...)

I ran into this error message while packing, and I can't solve it. Could someone possibly help?

Log:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogShaderCompilers: Error: SCW 5 Queued Jobs, Finished 0 single jobs
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogShaderCompilers: Error: Job 0 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32Skylight/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicy0LDRGamm
a32Skylight' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogShaderCompilers: Error: Job 1 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassVSTLightMapPolicyLQLDRGamma32/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassVertexShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassVSTLightMapPolicyLQLDRGamma32' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassVertexShader.usf' Entry 'Main' 
Permutation 0
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogShaderCompilers: Error: Job 2 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFNoLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFNoLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' 
Permutation 0
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogShaderCompilers: Error: Job 3 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFMobileMovableDirectionalLightAndSHIndirectPolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFMobileMovableDirectionalLightAndSHIndirect
PolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogShaderCompilers: Error: Job 4 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicy
INT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
LogAudioMixer: Display: 0: FrontLeft
LogAudioMixer: Display: 1: FrontRight
LogAudioMixer: Display: Audio Buffer Underrun (starvation) detected.
PackagingResults: Error: SCW 5 Queued Jobs, Finished 0 single jobs
PackagingResults: Error: Job 0 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32Skylight/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32Skylight' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.us
f' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
PackagingResults: Error: Job 1 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassVSTLightMapPolicyLQLDRGamma32/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassVertexShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassVSTLightMapPolicyLQLDRGamma32' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassVertexShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
PackagingResults: Error: Job 2 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFNoLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFNoLightMapPolicy0LDRGamma32' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
PackagingResults: Error: Job 3 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFMobileMovableDirectionalLightAndSHIndirectPolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFMobileMovableDirectionalLightAndSHIndirectPolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight' '/Engine/Private/Mobile
BasePassPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
PackagingResults: Error: Job 4 [Single] OmniHair/FLocalVertexFactory/TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight/0:/Engine/Private/MobileBasePassPixelShader.usf VF 'FLocalVertexFactory' Type 'TMobileBasePassPSFMobileDistanceFieldShadowsAndLQLightMapPolicyINT32_MAXLDRGamma32Skylight' '/Engine/Private/MobileBasePa
ssPixelShader.usf' Entry 'Main' Permutation 0
LogAudioMixer: Resetting audio stream to device id 
LogAudioMixer: Display: 0: FrontLeft
LogAudioMixer: Display: 1: FrontRight
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogOutputDevice: Warning:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   Script Stack (0 frames):
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: begin: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: Fatal error: [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 1236]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: Shader Compiling thread exception:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: Fatal error: [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 358]
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: ShaderCompileWorker crashed!
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:     Fatal error!
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff97184cd29 KERNELBASE.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff92707d066 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9270807a8 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff926d8e8cd UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff90510a5d6 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9050f2483 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff90511eb58 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9050ebd1c UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff905129947 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff92709898b UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff927091620 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9732174b4 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff973d826a1 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error:
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):   LogWindows: Error: end: stack for UAT
PackagingResults: Error: begin: stack for UAT
PackagingResults: Error: === Critical error: ===
PackagingResults: Error: Fatal error: [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 1236]
PackagingResults: Error: Shader Compiling thread exception:
PackagingResults: Error: Fatal error: [File:D:/Build/++UE4/Sync/Engine/Source/Runtime/Engine/Private/ShaderCompiler/ShaderCompiler.cpp] [Line: 358]
PackagingResults: Error: ShaderCompileWorker crashed!
PackagingResults: Error:     Fatal error!
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff97184cd29 KERNELBASE.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff92707d066 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9270807a8 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff926d8e8cd UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff90510a5d6 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9050f2483 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff90511eb58 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9050ebd1c UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff905129947 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff92709898b UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff927091620 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff9732174b4 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: [Callstack] 0x00007ff973d826a1 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
PackagingResults: Error: end: stack for UAT
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): Took 148,725105s to run UE4Editor-Cmd.exe, ExitCode=3
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): ERROR: Cook failed.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)):        (see C:\Users\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\D+EpicGames+gam+UE_4.26\Log.txt for full exception trace)
PackagingResults: Error: Cook failed.
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=25 (Error_UnknownCookFailure)
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (Multi:ASTC,DXT,ETC2)): BUILD FAILED
PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Cook Failure
```

I tried completely re-downloading all the required items.
I started a completely new project and it still runs into this error.